# problem with dictionary class

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary

I saw this article on msdn with the example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx

So i decided to give it a shot and try this out in my wpf application:

```
Dictionary<string, string> Dictionarycheck =
    new Dictionary<string, string>();

Dictionarycheck.Add("demo1");
```

Why this won't work? I get the error: Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Comment: Generally when you find a problem it isn't a problem with the .NET class. In this case, it isn't a problem with the Dictionary. If you dug ever so slightly deeper within the link you posted you'd see the Add method requires two string parameters. A key and a value.

Comment: I probably missed out on the key and value part. sorry.

Comment: This question makes me wince! [Are Some Questions Too Simple?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/)

Comment: Sorry i'm a beginner, i don't see any similar questions under the search. So please Mayank, that was a little unnecessary

Comment: @jeremychan Even the Intellisense of Visual Studio tell you what the error is - http://twitpic.com/45lnt5

Comment: @Mayank i just started using visual studio 5days ago

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two problems:

- You can't just add a key to a dictionary. You have to add a key/value pair
- You can't include statements directly in a class declaration - they have to be in constructors/methods/properties/etc. This is the direct cause of your problem, given your error message.

In other words, you've probably got something like this:

```
public class Test
{
    Dictionary<string, string> Dictionarycheck =
        new Dictionary<string, string>();

    Dictionarycheck.Add("demo1");
}
```

when it should be something like this:

```
public class Test
{
    public void DemoMethod()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> dictionaryCheck =
            new Dictionary<string, string>();

        dictionaryCheck.Add("demo1", "value1");
    }
}
```

(I've adjusted the name of the variable for convention, too.)

Comment: Thanks jon, i see where my problems are

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary(TKey, TValue)

So its Dictionarycheck.Add("Key", "Value");

Answer (score 1):

You are probably  writing the code outside of a method (like I just did to test it). Further, Dictionary.Add has two arguments.